# Return a Stream of Strings from a Path located in a HashMap

Tags: java, path, hashmap, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to learn about Streams and Paths.  I created a spellchecker in O(n) time and I'm trying to follow a guide that creates a spellchecker using Map / HashMap / Paths / and Streams.

I have created a Path to my word file and loaded it in.   I'm having trouble understanding how to print this list off.  I don't seem to have access to the list of words it creates when reading in from the Path.  I believe I have to return a Stream of Strings, just having trouble figuring out how this exactly works.

The input file is a dictionary of words, around 56k words.  One word per line.

## Sample Output (one long stream of words)

```
aardvarkaardwolfaaronabackabacusabaftabaloneabandonabandonedabandonmentabandonsabaseabasedabasementabashabashedabateabatedabatementabatesabattoirabattoirsabb
```

## Current Code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;


public class TheChecker {

    private static Map<String,Integer> dict = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Path dictOpen = Paths.get("/Users/sam/IdeaProjects/wordSpell/src/newWords.txt");

        try{
            //try opening file
            Spelling(dictOpen);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed path");
        }

        //fails to find dict even though I load it into memory the step before.
        for(String temp : dict) {
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
        //This produces one giant string of all words combined on one line.
        //Ideally I would like to use the known word method to find a single word
        for(String temp : dict.keySet() {
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }

    private static void Spelling(Path dictionaryFile) throws Exception{
        Stream.of(new String(Files.readAllBytes( dictionaryFile )).toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z ]","").split(" ")).forEach( (word) ->{
            dict.compute( word, (k,v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1  );
        });

    }

    private static Stream<String> known(Stream<String> words){
        return words.filter( (word) -> dict.containsKey(word) );
    }
    }
```

Comment: `Map` is not `Iterable`. Maybe you mean `for(String temp : dict.keySet())`?

Comment: So print out based on keySet or Value?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: if I system.out.println based on dic.keySet()  - I get 1 giant string output.  I'm trying to print out each word one at a time.

Comment: That means you only have 1 giant key. Can you include some sample input?

Comment: Yes - updated the main post

Comment: I don't see any sample input. But if words are separated by lines, why are you splitting on space?

Comment: I'll try updating that with  '\n'

Comment: By the way, your `Spelling()` method can be significantly simplified: `dict = Files.lines(dictionaryFile).map(String::toLowerCase).map(w -> w.replaceAll("[^a-z ]","").collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)));`

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try to implement that - I know it will throw a fit with '.collect' and 'Function.identity()'.  Any ideas on how to print out the dictionary of words 1 word at time line by line?

Comment: Why would it throw a fit? `Files.lines(...).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: The code itself is missing ')' somewhere, but I can't find it.  collect and Function show up in red when trying to build it out.  Might need a certain library not sure.  Building with intelliJ

Comment: Sorry, it's missing a `)` after `replaceAll`.

Comment: Still has an issue with collect and Function even with the addition ')' at 'replaceAll("[^a-z ]",""))'

Comment: I don't know what to say. It works fine for me.

Comment: Wouldn't that regex replace all spaces so each line will come out as single word all the time? Also, I'm pretty sure you want `Collectors.counting()` instead of `Collectors.summingInt(x->1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1 - for iterate in maps use

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : dict.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
    }
```

2 - Files.readAllBytes will read all file in one String. So if you have the words foo and bar , when you read with this function you will have : foobar.

Look for Files.readAllLines. http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.nio.file/Files/Java_Files_readAllLines_Path_path_Charset_cs_.htm